# Open-source DIY audio spectrum analyser and/or graphic equaliser

Tags: audio, frequency-measurement, test-equipment, cutoff-frequency

does anyone know of any OpenSource/DIY audio spectrum analyser projects

can they direct me to an article, video, pics

hackaday and instructionals style

also I.C's old or new that i could/should try

T. I. A   ;-)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you *do* have an electronics design question suitable for the site then please note that posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. See the site policy in [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: @Transistor many thanks for reply, im not sure by what you mean direct shopping, i hope you can help, thnks in advce

Comment: "*... can they direct me to an article, video, pic ...*" = direct shopping.

Comment: With or without a microcontroller? What type of display do you want?

Comment: hi, i am interested in in both with and without microcontroller along with trying to make a DIY VU meter i would like to eventually be able to buold a wide range equaliser maybe as big as with 31 bands, i am especially interested in the frequency control of the bass and sub bass area and being able to control down into the sub 60Hz region, thanks in advance for your time and help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find this useful [Link to Project](http://elm-chan.org/works/akilcd/report_e.html). There is an optimized FFT library for AVR microcontroller. Project uses SG12232C LCD, Atmega8 MCU and MAX293 filter chip. FFT done in 16bit fixed point, 128 points and sampling frequency 9.6kHz. Frequency resolution 75Hz.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. If this link changes or goes 404 then your answer will have no value. You should try to put the essential information in your answer itself, without directly copying the original source of course.

Comment: I understand, but question asks for projects and in this case link is essential in the answer. By the way this particular resource is quite old, online since more than 10 years.

Comment: thank you for helping this is my first post, i will try to follow all instructions and rules to help create and sustain this information exchange forum ;-)

Comment: hi, sorry for the very late response, this is exactly the kind of thing that i am thinking of, i am going to have a really good thorough read of this project and try to report back here asap as to what it can achieve towards me completing my current project, many thanks for the reply and taking the time to help ;-)